# is there anyway to extract browser history from an android phone by coding?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been searching online and I found some very old post in regards to my question but those solution does not work now. is it still possible to access/read/export browser history by coding on android studio?

Comment: Not exactly ethical.

Comment: As always, that would depend on the specific browser and whether it has any sort of API to access that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Chrome browser first, but you need to have root access before you proceed further then grab the History file from the location /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/ into PC. A Root Explorer may help.

Install an SQLite manager such as SQLiteman or DB Browser for SQLite in PC.

Both has the option under menu bar to export the database into an SQL file or a particular table into CSV file.

Well at least you now know where the history is stored, so you may find a relevant software to directly export the database into a CSV or XML file.

Comment: so is it impossible if I do not root my android phone?